# Access dynamically generated control from code behind

Tags: asp.net, postback, dynamic-controls

I load a piece of html which contains something like:

```
 <em> < input type="text" value="Untitled" name="ViewTitle" id="ViewTitle" runat="server"> </em>
```

into my control. The html is user defined, do please do not ask me to add them statically on the aspx page.

On my page, I have a placeholder and I can use

```
LiteralControl target = new LiteralControl ();

// html string contains user-defined controls
target.text = htmlstring
```

to render it property. My problem is, since its a html piece, even if i know the input box's id, i cannot access it using `FindControl("ViewTitle")` (it will just return null) because its rendered as a text into a Literal control and all the input controls were not added to the container's control collections. I definitely can use `Request.Form["ViewTitle"]` to access its value, but how can I set its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupaol's method is the prefer way of adding dynamic control to a page.

If you want to insert string, you can use [ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28.aspx).

However, it doesn't cause compilation for some controls such as PlaceHolder.

Comment: ParseControl is the right function for me. We receive user input template and need to dynamically generate controls from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your process is wrong, you are rendering a control to the client with the attribute: `runat="server"`

This attribute only works if the control was processed by the server, you are just rendering *as is*

Since your goal is to add a `TextBox` (correct me if I'm wrong), then why don't you just add a new `TextBox` to the form's controls collection???

Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = new TextBox { ID="myTextBoxID", Text="Some initial value" };

    this.myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textbox);
}
```

And to retrieve it:

```
var myDynamicTextBox = this.FindControl("myTextBoxID") as TextBox;
```

[I have created several working examples and they are online on my GitHub site, feel free to browse the code](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/tree/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/DynamicControls)